# Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, word-embeddings

I got the following warning:

```
94: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor with 1200012120 elements. This may consume a large amount of memory.
```

For the following code:

```
from wordbatch.extractors import WordSeq
import wordbatch
from keras.layers import Input,Embedding
...
wb = wordbatch.WordBatch(normalize_text, extractor=(WordSeq, {"seq_maxlen": MAX_NAME_SEQ}), procs=NUM_PROCESSOR)
wb.dictionary_freeze = True
full_df["ws_name"] = wb.fit_transform(full_df["name"])
...
name = Input(shape=[full_df["name"].shape[1]], name="name")
emb_name = Embedding(MAX_TEXT, 50)(name)
...
```

That is I make use of WordSeq (from WordBatch) output from the Embedding layer of a GRU network. How should I modify the code to make it work without converting to dense tensor?

Comment: I don't think that is an error, that is a warning explicitly put up by the guy written the code to make sure that you know what you are doing.

Comment: @KiriteeGak changed - changing from a sparse matrix to a dense tensor is something not right, hope to find a better method here

Comment: hello. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @YuGu Were you working in SUTD?

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue with the Embedding layer in Keras. [The solution](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4365#issuecomment-260482550) is to explicitly use a TensorFlow optimizer, like here:

`model.compile(loss='mse',
               optimizer=TFOptimizer(tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)))`